# swiftで文字列に変数を埋め込む際

Tags: swift

swiftで文字列に変数を埋め込む際、例えば

```
let item = "金の剣"
print("ゲットしたアイテムは\(item)")
```

という感じにただ文字列に`\()`を埋め込めばいいですが、なぜかそれでは動かなく、
`\(())` ←こういうふうに２重に囲まなければ動かなかったのですが、これはなぜでしょうか？

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myPickerView: UIPickerView!
    let compos = [["月", "火", "水", "木", "金"], ["早朝", "午前中", "昼間", "夜間"]]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return compos.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        let compo = compos[component]
        return compo.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if component == 0 {
            return 50
        } else {
            return 100
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let item = compos[component][row]
        return item
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        //選ばれた項目
        let item = compos[component] [row]
        print("\(item)が選ばれた")
        //現在選択されている行番号
        let row1 = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let row2 = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        print("現在選択されている行番号 \((row1, row2))")

        // 現在選択されている項目名
        let item1 = self.pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow: row1, forComponent: 0)
        let item2 = self.pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow: row2, forComponent: 1)
        print("現在選択されている項目名 \((item1!, item2!))")
        print("-------------")

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        myPickerView.delegate = self
        myPickerView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Comment: あなたが書かれたように普通に`\(...)`の中に式を書けば、その式の値が埋め込まれるはずです。(あなたの例では \ の後に空白が置かれていますが、そう言うものが存在してはいけません。単にサイトへの書き込みの時の問題でしょうか?)「こういうふうに２重に囲まなければ動かなかった」際のコードをお示しいただければ、何か気がつくことがあるかもしれません。ご自身の質問は「編集」から修正できますので、適切なコード例を追記してください。

Comment: 空白はstack overflow側の問題で、空白を入れないとバックスラッシュが表示されないのです。ちなみにコードはこちらです

Answer (score 3):

ご質問に掲載された例はこの辺りのことでしょうか?

```
print("現在選択されている行番号 \((row1, row2))")
```

コメント中に「`\(...)`の中に式を書けば、その式の値が埋め込まれる」と書きましたが、ここでの「式」は1つの式です。

もし、`row1`と`row2`と、2つの式を埋め込みたいのであれば、本来は例えば次のようにしないといけません。

```
print("現在選択されている行番号 (\(row1), \(row2))")
```

2つの値を埋め込んでいるのだから、`\(...)`も2ついるわけです。

だのに、あなたのコードが正しく動くのは`(..., ...)`が[タプル(tuple)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID329)になっているからです。タブルは1つの式なので、`\(...)`の中に埋め込むことにより埋め込み文字列中で使えているわけです。

---

似たような(見た目上は)二重のカッコは、関数呼び出しの際にも発生し得ます。

```
func myFunc(_ tuple: (Int, Int)) {
    print("tuple=\(tuple)")
}
myFunc((1, 2)) //->tuple=(1, 2)
myFunc(1, 2) //->Global function 'myFunc' expects a single parameter of type '(Int, Int)'
```

(外側の`myFunc(...)`の方が関数呼び出しとしてのカッコ、内側の`(1, 2)`がタプルを作るためのカッコです。)

このように見た目が「二重のカッコ」になる例はちょくちょくあるのに、コードをお示しいただくまで気づかなかったはお恥ずかしい限りですが、1つの式としてタプルを使うと言う感覚はわかっていただけたのではないかと思います。

(ちなみに`myFunc(1, 2)`のような呼び出し方は、昔のSwiftでは許可されていたので、さらにややこしかったです。)

---

ちなみに \ を含むコードを本文中に入れたい場合、バッククオートで囲んで`...`のようにしてやるとうまくいくときがあります。(\ は引用文字なんでうまくいかない時もあります。)またコードブロック全体をコード引用するときは先頭と最後に ``` (バッククオート3つ)だけの行を置いてやると囲まれた全体がコードとして成形されるようになります。ご参考までに。

Comment: なんということでしょう。悩みはスッキリと消え完璧な回答を頂きました。まだ初心者なので質問の仕方も下手だったかなと思いましたが...本で勉強しているのですがサンプルコードにそれが書いてなかったのですがむしろ書いてなくて良かったです笑　ありがとうございました